# Chart point hover error

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular-chart

I use angular-chart.js (1.0.2) and chart.js (2.5.0) and have a problem: the point are hovered just when I directly hover it, but when I put mouse a little bit higher hover on point is lost.
I use standard configuration:

```
 $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
 $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];

 $scope.data = [
   [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
   [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
 ];
```

Due to current application angular version I can't use another version of angular-chart.js.

Could somebody please help me with this?

[image with styles - click on me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaNfZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set `intersect: false` for the `tooltips` object in your chart options, like so ....

```
$scope.options = {
    tooltips: {
        intersect: false
    },
    //other options goes here...
}
```

This will make the tooltips show even if the cursor is not directly hovered over the point.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you. But styles are not as when i hover point by mouse. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: what styles? can you share an image?

Comment: I updated image. Oh, it's no problem with checking mark :-)

Comment: One more little question: is there any way to create vertical red line that will go behind mouse cursor? It will be conveniently on chart with lots of points.

Comment: um.. maybe, but that's a different question. you should rather ask a new question with additional details for that